# Kubernetes - apiservice Available=False

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm currently running Kubernetes cluster in Azure. I am having an issue where my metrics-server is saying  False (FailedDiscoveryCheck)when running kubectl get apiservice. I have tried restarting the cluster, the services and pods relating to the server, to no avail. Does anyone know any troubleshooting steps I can take or how I can restart this specific apiservice?

Thanks,

Comment: What CNI are you using? Can you try setting metrics-server as hostNetwork?

Comment: Are you running a AKS or kubeadm cluster in Azure? If AKS, metrics-server should be shipped "out of the box". See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-scale?tabs=azure-cli#autoscale-pods)

Comment: @VasiliAngapov How do i do that?

Comment: @adan11 Have you tried to find it? Not clear how it's installed, but [here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/doc-detail/123997.htm) is an example what should be done to run metrics-server with hostNetwork enabled.